# Creating a web service to expose website functionality in drupal

Tags: android, web-services, drupal, service

I have a website which is already created in Drupal. In one section it consists of a form with different fields which on submit returns you the result from the database. 
I want to create an android application to access this search functionality by the form created in Android and also display the results there. Is there a way by which I can write some sort of web service which doesn't change any code for the website and give me desired results.

Can somebody guide me what can I do here? I don't have much knowledge of Drupal but I am familiar with PHP.

Answer (score 0):

You will want to look at using the [Services](http://drupal.org/project/services) module. Sumit Kataria gave a good presentation on how one would go about [developing android/iphone apps using Drupal as a base](http://chicago2011.drupal.org/sessions/developing-apps-iphone-ipad-android-using-drupal-base-system) at DrupalCon Chicago 2011 (there is a video of the session). He covers more then what you are looking for, but does provides a good introduction on how to go about using services.